# vim regex multiline: search works, match() doesn't

Tags: regex, vim, match, multiline

Let's say I have this buffer:

```
a
b
c
(
1
2
3
)
@
#
$
```

I would like, in a vimscript to get the contents of line between parentheses.

```
/(\n\(.\n\)*)
```

highlights exactly what I want. But I don't succeed to get this with something like:

```
let pattern = '(\n\(.\n\)*)'
match(getline(1, '$'), pattern)
```

I try a lot of stuffs, such as:

```
match(join(getline(1,'$'), '\n'), pattern)
```

, even double quotes for pattern, but nothing works... Any idea ?

(my aim is not necessary to make this match() works, but just to get the result from a buffer to a vimscript)

Comment: Perhaps, `let pattern = '(\n\(.\n\)*)'`?

Comment: You're right, edited.

Comment: It looks to me you are looking for `(\n\(.\{-}\))`.

Comment: Just as an FYI there are multiline regex atoms. So you probably want something like `'(\(\_.\{-}\))`

Comment: I tried 'help /\\_', but I thought '\\_' was just available while preceding the listed character. Good to know it is not !

Comment: @Gaut the actual help is `:help /\_.` don't know why its not listed with the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your first try (`match(getline(1, '$'), pattern)`), Vim tries to find the pattern *inside* each line; as your pattern is multi-line, it never matches.

So, your second try goes to a right direction, because you try to join the lines, then the pattern would effectively match... Unless you use `'\n'` as a glue for the join : this string is litterally replaced by a backslash `\` followed by an `n` character. Just replace single quotes by double quotes, then special chars will be parsed.

So, this version will work better:

```
echo matchstr(join(getline(1,'$'), "\n"), pattern)
```